# Is there a way to convert GIMP steps to manipulate an image to GEGL function calls?

Tags: python, image-processing, gimp, gegl

I have a set of steps in GIMP that I want to automate in Python. How can I translate what a GIMP tool does to GEGL functions?

This started with me trying to write python scripts that call some GIMP steps (since I want the source code to live in a lambda function) However, I soon found out GIMP runs the python scripts not the other way around.

After more digging and reading I found a post that pointed me to GEGL. After confirming there existed python bindings for GEGL I decided to search for information about their API and how GIMP uses GEGL. Found nothing so far.

The list of steps are more or less:

1. Curve bends
2. Gaussian blur
3. Linear burn
4. Change saturation
5. Merging layers
6. Transforms

Comment: There seems to be only 1 question on StackOverflow about GEGL since 2014. I wouldn't hold your breath.

Comment: As an alternative, I would suggest to look into [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html), an imaging library for python. I'm not an expert, but should be able to do the things you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

The GEGL source is [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gegl)

There are two Python examples, [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gegl/blob/master/examples/simple-graph.py) and [there](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gegl/blob/master/examples/xml-graph.py)